# C# Save text to speech to MP3 file

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

I am wondering if there is a way to save text to speech data to an mp3 or Wav file format to be played back at a later time?

```
SpeechSynthesizer reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
reader.Rate = (int)-2;
reader.Speak("Hello this is an example expression from the computers TTS engine in C-Sharp);
```

I am trying to get that saved externally so I can play it back later. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are [multiple options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer_methods.aspx) such as saving to an existing stream. If you want to create a new WAV file, you can use the [SetOutputToWaveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586883.aspx) method.

```
reader.SetOutputToWaveFile(@"C:\MyWavFile.wav");
```

Answer (score 9):

Not my answer, copy paste from [How do can I use LAME to encode an wav to an mp3 c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166140/how-do-can-i-use-lame-to-encode-an-wav-to-an-mp3-c-sharp/23947113#23947113)

---

Easiest way in .Net 4.0:

Use the visual studio Nuget Package manager console:

```
Install-Package NAudio.Lame
```

Code Snip: Send speech to a memory stream, then save as mp3:

```
//reference System.Speech
using System.Speech.Synthesis; 
using System.Speech.AudioFormat;

//reference Nuget Package NAudio.Lame
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.Lame; 


using (SpeechSynthesizer reader = new SpeechSynthesizer()) {
    //set some settings
    reader.Volume = 100;
    reader.Rate = 0; //medium

    //save to memory stream
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    reader.SetOutputToWaveStream(ms);

    //do speaking
    reader.Speak("This is a test mp3");

    //now convert to mp3 using LameEncoder or shell out to audiograbber
    ConvertWavStreamToMp3File(ref ms, "mytest.mp3");
}

public static void ConvertWavStreamToMp3File(ref MemoryStream ms, string savetofilename) {
    //rewind to beginning of stream
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (var retMs = new MemoryStream())
    using (var rdr = new WaveFileReader(ms))
    using (var wtr = new LameMP3FileWriter(savetofilename, rdr.WaveFormat, LAMEPreset.VBR_90)) {
        rdr.CopyTo(wtr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried same code of yours , works perfect at local but unable to create mp3 file on server. Do you have any idea what configuration we need on server?

Comment: you need to deploy some dlls on the server for naudio to work e.g. did you put libmp3lame.32.dll and libmp3lame.64.dll in the same folder as your exe?

Comment: Yes i do have them, i have them in the Bin folder and the root directory as well.But When I run this application on server it create a mp3 file with the size of 2kb always independent of the very large text you enter and the mp3 doesn't play. I think due to some issues on server it cannot create mp3 properly.

Comment: sounds like you need to do more digging, I do not know what the issue is, at least..

Answer (score 1):

Often, if something works on a dev workstation but not on a production server, its a permissions issue. two thoughts:
Does Lame create temporary files somewhere? If so the IIS process needs write permissions there.
When writing the output file, again the IIS process needs permission to write that. `ConvertWavStreamToMp3File(ref ms, "mytest.mp3");` "mytest.mp3" will probably need to be a full path, using `Server.MapPath()`