# NAudio lame convert text to mp3 not working properly on server c# web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, naudio, naudio-framework

I have been using System.Speech for converting text to speech and using this code

[C# Save text to speech to MP3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021302/c-sharp-save-text-to-speech-to-mp3-file/26502663)

it works perfectly fine at local but not working properly on server, when i upload it on server it create mp3 of size 2kb only which doesn't play even. I don't know what is it on server who is blocking creating mp3 on server . I have uploaded libmp3lame.32.dll and libmp3lame.64.dll also in the Bin folder and on Root Folder . But Still its not working properly. Can anybody help me to find what issue probably i am facing right now on server ?

Comment: Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598849/asp-net-web-application-on-deploy-system-speech-dll-object-not-getting-set-to

Answer (score 2):

It was an issue of application pool setting over server . This linked helped me to solve my issue.

[ASP.NET Web Application - on deploy, System.Speech.dll object not getting set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598849/asp-net-web-application-on-deploy-system-speech-dll-object-not-getting-set-to)